# ERROR 000338 when appending two datasets into one with arcpy

Tags: arcpy, append, error-000338

In an enterprise geodatabase with three datasets I'm trying to append two of the datasets into the third, however I get an error which states that *Inputs must be either all Feature Classes, Tables or Rasters; not mixed.*. This seems odd as the datasets only consists of Feature classes.

The feature classes is structured with the same name but a different code suffix: 
eg:
lsat_6865 : lsat_6866
lsar_6865 : lsar_6866
lsar_6865_anno : lsar_6866_anno

The number codes should be stripped from the name in the resulting dataset.

The entire error message below:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\scripts\test\append.py", line 26, in <module>
>     arcpy.Append_management([WorkspaceES + '/' + fc + MCodeES, WorkspaceGT + '/' + fc + MCodeGT], fc, 'TEST', '', '')
>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 4271, in Append
>     raise e
> ExecuteError: 
> ERROR 000338: Inputs must be either all Feature Classes, Tables or Rasters; not mixed.
> ```

```
import arcpy

MCodeES = '6865'
MCodeGT  = '6866'

WorkspaceES   = 'C:/scripts/sde_mcde.sde/sde_mcde.sde.ADO.ES_tab'
WorkspaceGT   = 'C:/scripts/sde_mcde.sde/sde_mcde.sde.ADO.GT_tab'

arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:/scripts/sde_mcde.sde/sde_mcde.sde.ADO.GT_tab.ADO.ES_GT.FK'

# Get a list of data sets and feature class
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
fcList.sort()

# Loop through the list
for fc in fcList:
    arcpy.TruncateTable_management(fc)
    if fc.partition('_anno')[1].strip() == '_anno':
        arcpy.Append_management([WorkspaceES + '/' + fc.partition('_anno')[0].strip() + '_' + MCodeES + '_anno', WorkspaceGT + '/' + fc.partition('_anno')[0].strip() + '_' + MCodeGT + '_anno'], fc, 'NO_TEST', '', '') 
        print(fc)
    else:
        arcpy.Append_management([WorkspaceES + '/' + fc + MCodeES, WorkspaceGT + '/' + fc + MCodeGT], fc, 'TEST', '', '')
        print(fc)

print('/nPress Enter to continue ...')
raw_input()
```

Comment: Try buildong your path with [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join). Do something like `os.path.join(WorkspaceES, fc + MCodeES)` instead of doing `WorkspaceES + '/' + fc + MCodeES`. change this for all your path and see if that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks for responding but it gives the same error message unfortunately.

Comment: Just to be 100% sure: is `C:/scripts/sde_mcde.sde/sde_mcde.sde.ADO.ES_tab/lsat_6865` a feature class? I suggest you first try to test only the Append part of your code from the Python window with two specific datasets and see if it works there. Also, it is probably worth `print`ing the value of your fc when you are using it so that you can see what is actually failing (to debug).

Comment: Exactly, it's a feature class. Points, polygon, lines and annotations in the datasets. I tried to run merely the append part but got the same error, also I tried removing everything but the polygons but still got the same error.

Comment: I think you need to explain what is in your workspaces; looking at the logic it tries to find _anno, if not then creates dataset names ending with numbers. I would build that outside the tool, print it to see if the expected names are well formed and test they actually exist in the workspace before calling the tool. Building file paths inside tool parameters in my opinion is a bit sloppy as then you don't if it the tool that is failing or you constructing bad syntax.

Comment: In two of the datasets I have a hundred or so feature classes with the same schema, eg: the feature class abc exists in two datasets but with a different number code abc_6865 and abc_6866. The number code represents different administrative units. The annotation classes are named abc_6865_anno. I want to merge them into a third dataset as they share geographic borders. In that dataset the feature classes are just named abc and abc_anno without the number code.